# rigidbody.AddForce() don't make my player jump at the same height everytime in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So i made a player with a rigidbody and a child game object "feet", i also added a layer "floor" to every plateforme my player can jump off so i can use Physics.CheckSphere() to see if my player is actually on the ground and can jump. In this last case i add a force to my rigidbody with a ForceMode.Impulse. Everything work except that sometimes the player do a little jump and sometimes a higher jump. Here is my code :

```
    [SerializeField] private float speed;
    [SerializeField] private float jumpForce;
    [SerializeField] private Transform feet = null;
    [SerializeField] private LayerMask floorMask;

    private Vector3 direction;
    private Rigidbody rb;

    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        direction = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0f, Input.GetAxis("Vertical")) * speed;
        transform.LookAt(transform.position + new Vector3(direction.x, 0, direction.z));

    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector3(direction.x, rb.velocity.y, direction.z);

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            if (Physics.CheckSphere(feet.position, 0.1f, floorMask))
            {
                rb.AddForce(Vector3.up * jumpForce, ForceMode.Impulse);
            }
        }
    }
```

I replaced the AddForce method with velocity and it seems to work but AddForce isn't the proper way to do jumps ?

```
rb.velocity = new Vector3(rb.velocity.x, 1 * jumpForce, rb.velocity.z);
```

Comment: because the velocity still has value and addForce as it named add value to the current velocity. if you reset velocity `rb.velocity = Vector3.zero;` and add Force it will work

Comment: Both are proper ways .. which ever works for you ;)

Comment: Yup it works perfectly with 'rb.velocity = Vector3.zero;' thank you @Mohamed Awad, but when i did my tests i wasn't mooving so the current velocity should be null ? Also i don't really understand why adding a value to a current velocity make some of my jumps smaller.

Comment: @derHugo yeah but even if i find an other way to do something i like to understand why the things i did before dosn't work ^^

Comment: oh, maybe you need to see some physics articles, simply... to jump, it's required positive velocity on the y-axis, the gravity resists this force so the velocity value decreases until = 0; after that, the character will fall down, means velocity value for y-axis is negative, and ground, of course, make character steady so velocity falls back to 0;

Comment: I searched for a long time before posting this question but i wasn't expecting this problem, thank you very much for your explanations it is clear to me now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using ForceMode.Impulse is the ideal way to implement a jump with RigidBody. I beleive you need to take your button input out of FixedUpdate() and place it into regular Update(). Then use a bool such as "canJump". This is because your input is being read inside FixedUpdate(); Which is only called every other frame with the physics engine. Also, your rb.velocity.y should be set to 0 when touching ground.

```
void Update() {
    direction = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0f, Input.GetAxis("Vertical")) * speed;
    transform.LookAt(transform.position + new Vector3(direction.x, 0, direction.z));


    bool canJump = Input.GetKeyDown(keyCode.Space) ? true : false;
}

void FixedUpdate() {

    if (Physics.CheckSphere(feet.position, 0.1f, floorMask)) {
        
        if (canJump)
            rb.AddForce(Vector3.up * jumpForce, ForceMode.Impulse);
        
        else
            rb.velocity = new Vector3(direction.x, 0, direction.z);
    }
     
    else
        rb.velocity = new Vector3(direction.x, rb.velocity.y, direction.z);
}
```

Comment: Oh okey i understand my mistake thank you very much ! it works perfectly i juste have to instanciate the boolean outside Update() function. I saw almost nobody setting the velocity.y to 0 when touching ground in the tutorials i watched thank you for telling me that and i think this is also why @Mohamed Awad told me to write this line just before jumping : rb.velocity = Vector3.zero;

Comment: Yes, I spent a lot of time creating character controllers over the past years. It may not seem necesarry right now, but depending on how complext your ground is it can cause stuttering, because gravity is constantly pushing the character down; Which may not be what you want. So setting the y velocity to zero fixes the possiblity of that happening... But like I said, depends on what you have set up

Comment: Yeah i think that's a good practice and i'll do it everytime even if it can work without it sometimes ^^.

Comment: @Dusk did your issue get resolved? please mark the question as answered if it did :D

Comment: Oh yes of course it resolved sorry i don't often ask questions on stackOverflow how do i mark it as answered ?

Comment: @Dusk if my answer was the one that helped you, then you can mark my answer.

Comment: Hey ! i've used the same code in a 2D game (with raycast instead of checkSphere to see if the player is grounded) and after more testing i found some issues with this code. First the boolean "canJump" should be set to false in the FixedUpdate after every tests because i found that sometimes my player didn't jump (maybe the boolean was reset to false before i jump) 1/2

Comment: and also the line 'rb.velocity = new Vector3(direction.x, 0, direction.z);' souldn't be in the else it rather be just before 'if (canJump)' because sometimes when jumping from a plateform to a higher one and rejumping just after, the second jump was smaller than it should be (exactly the same issue that i had in my first post). Maybe i'm wrong, but those changes solved my problems so i hope it can help ^^

Comment: @Dusk I see, this code was never tested, so thanks for letting me know. The reason I chose to put the vector 3 in the else statment; Was because if your character was to walk off the edge of a platform, then you would want gravity to kick in... But then when the character hits the ground again, you would reset the Y-velocity to 0

Comment: yes sure the rb.velocity = new Vector3(direction.x, rb.velocity.y, direction.z) should be in the else statment so the gravity apply when you'r not grounded (like when you walk off an edge) but in fact it's the vector3 that reset to 0 the Y-velocity which should be in any case when you are grounded in that way you are sure that your velocity is at 0 before jumping with AddForce cause i think the issue was smth like rejumping at the exact moment when you'r grounded again so you don't have time to reset the velocity to 0 before the AddForce. Anyway i hope i'm clear and thanks for your response ;)